# Swift : type String doesn't conform to protocol AnyObject

Tags: swift, ios8, nsdictionary

I probably missed something basic in swift. Can't get an array out of NSDictionary value.

The code is:

```
import Foundation

//need to add Settings bundle to project in order to run this test.
class CompileError {

    func foo(){
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "bundle");
        if(path == nil) {
            NSLog("Could not find Settings.bundle");
            return;
        }

        let settings:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:path!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Root.plist"));
        var preferences:Array = settings.objectForKey("PreferenceSpecifiers") as Array //Get Compile Error: type String doesn't conform to protocol AnyObject  
    }
}
```

Seeing in debugger, Preferences object has an array for key "PreferenceSpecifiers", but i just can't cast it. 
If i try:

```
var preferences:Array = settings.objectForKey("PreferenceSpecifiers")?.Array
```

it compiles but the preferences object is set to nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though interesting, I'm afraid your answer is not really solving your problem. The reason casting to `NSArray` "worked" is because `NSArray` does not have an associated type, while Swift's `Array` does. A here relevant summary of `Array` **struct** would be:

```
struct Array<T> : MutableCollectionType {
    typealias Element = T
    init<S : SequenceType>(s: S)
    // and much more – just Command-click on `Array` and check it out for yourself
```

Evidently, `Array` is a generic struct collection, i.e. its type is only fully specified when the type of its `Element`s (or `T`s) is known. So `as NSArray` is not so much "the correct instruction" as it is a postponement of the time it will become necessary to get to grips with generics. This, however, should be enjoyable and rewarding since, as a language, Swift is at once new and vigorously evolving **and** very old and experienced, inheriting all the good stuff from so many other languages...

Briefly, though:

```
let arr: NSArray = [1,2,3,4,5]         
// even after casting to `NSArray`, `arr` is still an `[AnyObject]`
//     e.g. try this:

// arr is [AnyObject]                  // compiler error: 'is' test is always true

let ints = arr as [Int]                // --> [1,2,3,4,5]

// or more safely:

if let ints = arr as? [Int] {
    ints                               // --> [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

And closer to your case:

```
let array: NSArray = ["settings", "etc", "..."] // just simulating the objects you are working with

let settings: NSDictionary = ["PreferenceSpecifiers": array] // ditto

if let prefs = settings["PreferenceSpecifiers"] as? [String] {
    prefs                              // --> ["settings", "etc", "..."]
    // this is only if *all* PreferenceSpecifiers are NSStrings, 
    //     otherwise, you'll have to downcast them as an when you access them
    //     rather than wholesale, as I did here...
} else {
    // ouch, no preferences found
}
```

#### From *Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project* (Documentation):

> **Arrays**
>
> Swift automatically bridges between the Array type and the NSArray
>   class. When you bridge from an NSArray object to a Swift array, the
>   resulting array is of type [AnyObject]. An object is AnyObject
>   compatible if it is an instance of an Objective-C or Swift class, or
>   if the object can be bridged to one. You can bridge any NSArray object
>   to a Swift array because all Objective-C objects are AnyObject
>   compatible. Because all NSArray objects can be bridged to Swift
>   arrays, the Swift compiler replaces the NSArray class with [AnyObject]
>   when it imports Objective-C APIs.
>
> After you bridge an NSArray object to a Swift array, you can also
>   downcast the array to a more specific type. Unlike casting from the
>   NSArray class to the [AnyObject] type, downcasting from AnyObject to a
>   more specific type is not guaranteed to succeed. The compiler cannot
>   know for certain until runtime that all of the elements in the array
>   can be downcasted to the type you specified. As a result, downcasting
>   from [AnyObject] to [SomeType] returns an optional value. For example,
>   if you know that a Swift array contains only instances of the UIView
>   class (or a subclass of the UIView class), you can downcast the array
>   of AnyObject type elements to an array of UIView objects. If any
>   element in the Swift array is not actually a UIView object at runtime,
>   the cast returns nil.
>
> **Dictionaries**
>
> In addition to arrays, Swift also automatically bridges between the
>   Dictionary type and the NSDictionary class. When you bridge from an
>   NSDictionary object to a Swift dictionary, the resulting dictionary is
>   of type [NSObject: AnyObject]. You can bridge any NSDictionary object
>   to a Swift dictionary because all Objective-C objects are AnyObject
>   compatible. Recall that an object is AnyObject compatible if it is an
>   instance of an Objective-C or Swift class, or if it can be bridged to
>   one. All NSDictionary objects can be bridged to Swift dictionaries, so
>   the Swift compiler replaces the NSDictionary class with [NSObject:
>   AnyObject] when it imports Objective-C APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Found out. Just assumed that Array is same as NSArray and it isn't.

The correct instruction is:

```
var preferences = settings.objectForKey("PreferenceSpecifiers") as NSArray
```